# Forest plot with log-transformed model by metafor package in R

Tags: r

I am meta-analysing prevalence of medications with the `rma.glmm` command in the `metafor` package. The log-transform is used as they are follow the binomial distribution.

So, my model is:

```
med_A<-rma.glmm(xi=A, ni=Sample_size, measure="PLO")
```

The forest plot is made with the following code and the result is attached below.

```
forest(med_A, atransf = transf.ilogit, ilab = cbind(A, Sample_size), 
       ilab.xpos = c(-7,-5), slab = Study, refine=1)
```

The scale looks so weird as 1.00 appears twice and it doesn't distribute equal. How could I change scale and make transformed-back forest plot?

[image: Forest plot of medication A]

Comment: No data to work with. Contact the package author if you think there is a bug in his plot method.

Comment: Small correction: The **logit** transformation is used (not just the log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `forest(med_A)` here, you will see that the default x-axis tick marks are drawn at `-6, -4, ..., 6, 8`. So if you use `atransf=transf.ilogit`, the two highest values are `0.9975274` and `0.9996646` (just try: `transf.ilogit(c(6,8))`), which become `1.00` when rounded to two decimal places. If you do `forest(med_A, atransf=transf.ilogit, digits=3)` you will see that those are really two distinct values. So this is not a bug in the function.

It's a bit tricky to get a decent forest plot here (also because of study 3, which is really an outlier). One thing you could do is set the tick marks manually. For example:

```
forest(med_A, atransf=transf.ilogit, at=transf.logit(c(.01, .1, .5, .8, .95, .99, .9999)))
```

Note that you cannot use 1 for the highest value, since this would be `Inf`. After rounding, the plot will still show `1.00` for the highest tick mark, but this is a bit misleading, since the "real" 1 cannot be shown on the logit scale.

Instead of transforming the x-axis values, you may want to transform the values themselves. So:

```
forest(med_A, transf=transf.ilogit, refline=.5)
```

The CIs will then be asymmetric, but that's correct due to using a non-linear (back)transformation.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang! You made a clear point here! However, I am still struggling with adding specified point on X scale. I tried                 forest(med_A, atransf=transf.ilogit, at=transf.logit(c(.01, .1, .5, .8, .95, .99, .9999)))  But diamond went to one side and the scale doesn't seem correct at all. And other way to change scale? Many thanks!  graph: http://127.0.0.1:47085/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=1200&height=900

Comment: That link doesn't work. Not sure what you mean by "the scale doesn't seem correct at all" -- if you use `atransf=transf.ilogit`, the scale is now on a logit scale, so things become very stretched out as you move away from 0.5. That's to be expected. Again, if you don't like this, then you could use `transf=transf.ilogit`, so you transform the values directly.

Comment: Oh, that tip does help! The forest plot looks normal now! I did figure out what happened at beginning. It is just I define xlim too large..Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem is resolved. Feel free to accept my answer then.